# Exec arguments not providing expected results

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, c++14

I'm implementing two programs which will act as ALU and CPU,The CPU will read inputs from a file as 3 arguments (num,operator,num) and pass those arguments to ALU.exe which will then compute and return the result the arguments are passed but still not returning the desired output

NOTE:-I was going to post the segment with problems only but last time I posted a question here comments were asking for entire code

**CPU.exe**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main () {
ifstream obj;
const char *path = "/home/ALU.exe";
obj.open("sample.txt",ios::app);
string arg1,arg2;
string op;


while(
getline(obj,arg1,',') && getline(obj,op,',') && getline(obj,arg2,'\n')
) {
pid_t pid = fork();


if(pid==0) {
char* args[3];
char a1[arg1.size()+1];
char a2[arg2.size()+1];
char o[op.size()+1];
arg1.copy(a1,arg1.size()+1);
a1[arg1.size()]='\0';
arg2.copy(a2,arg2.size()+1);
a2[arg2.size()]='\0';
op.copy(o,op.size()+1);
o[op.size()]='\0';
args[1]=a1;
args[2]=o;
args[3]=a2;
//args[0]=arg1.c_str();
//args[1]=op.c_str();
//args[2]=arg2.c_str();
execv(path,args);
}

wait();
}
return 0;
}
```

The segment where arguments are sent to ALU.exe

```
while(
getline(obj,arg1,',') && getline(obj,op,',') && getline(obj,arg2,'\n')
) {
pid_t pid = fork();


if(pid==0) {
char* args[3];
char a1[arg1.size()+1];
char a2[arg2.size()+1];
char o[op.size()+1];
arg1.copy(a1,arg1.size()+1);
a1[arg1.size()]='\0';
arg2.copy(a2,arg2.size()+1);
a2[arg2.size()]='\0';
op.copy(o,op.size()+1);
o[op.size()]='\0';
args[1]=a1;
args[2]=o;
args[3]=a2;
//args[0]=arg1.c_str();
//args[1]=op.c_str();
//args[2]=arg2.c_str();
execv(path,args);
}

wait();
}
```

and below is the code for ALU.cpp

**ALU.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int Operation(int a,char* op,int b) {

char operand = *op;
if(operand == '+') {
return a+b;
}
if(operand == '-') {
return a-b;
}
if(operand == '/'){
return a/b;
}
if(operand == '*'){
return a*b;
}
else {
cout << "invalid" << endl;
return -999;
}
}
int main (int argc,char* argv[]) {

//if(argc!=3) {
//cout << "Exit" << endl;
//return -9999;
//}

for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
cout << "Arg " << i << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
}
int arg1,arg2;
char* op;
arg1= atoi(argv[1]);
arg2= atoi(argv[3]);
op = argv[2];
int result = Operation(arg1,op,arg2);
cout << "result: " << result << endl;
return result;

}
```

and the sample file contains this data

```
3,+,6
12,-,4
3,*,10
```

but the results obtained are as follows

```
 invalid
invalid
result: -999
result: -999
invalid
result: -999
```

I've been debugging for days and still can't find any solution to my problem I've searched for previous questions with issues like this on stack overflow but still no success this is why I'm asking this question here,I'm sorry if there's an issue with my fluency in English which makes it hard to understand or I've been doing something which is frowned upon by the stackoverflow community but I've tried my best to write a question keeping everything in mind everyone tells me here

EDIT:

Trying to print out the arguments results in an error so this is a problem with type casting then maybe?

when I try to

```
cout << a1 << o << a2 << endl;
```

This is the error I receive

```
3b��*c�����s
10�����p
*** Error in `12��-c�����s
4c�����p
*** Error in `3b��+c�����s
6c�����p
*** Error in `b���b��xd��-���*c��10���b��xd��S�b���b��xd��-���
*** Error in `c���b��xd��-���-c��4c���b��xd��S�c���b��xd��-���
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfb162b0 ***
./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfb162b0 ***
b���b��xd��-���*c��10���b��xd��S�b���b��xd��-���
b���b��xd��-���*c��10���b��xd��S�b���b��xd��-���
*** Error in `*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfb162b0 ***
./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfb162b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb7bf8377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb7bfe2f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dc31)[0xb7bfec31]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb7dd2d88]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev+0x25)[0xb7e6c985]
./a.out[0x8048f5a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb7ba9637]
./a.out[0x8048b11]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
09621000-09646000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7a00000-b7a21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7a21000-b7b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7b39000-b7b3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7b3c000-b7b8f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b8f000-b7b90000 r--p 00052000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b90000-b7b91000 rw-p 00053000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b91000-b7d41000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d41000-b7d43000 r--p 001af000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d43000-b7d44000 rw-p 001b1000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d44000-b7d47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7d47000-b7d63000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393625     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d63000-b7d64000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 393625     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d64000-b7ed1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed1000-b7ed2000 ---p 0016d000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed2000-b7ed7000 r--p 0016d000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed7000-b7ed8000 rw-p 00172000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed8000-b7edb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef0000-b7ef1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef1000-b7ef2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef2000-b7ef5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b7ef5000-b7ef7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7ef7000-b7f1a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7f1a000-b7f1b000 r--p 00022000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7f1b000-b7f1c000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bfaf8000-bfb19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb7bf8377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb7bfe2f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dc31)[0xb7bfec31]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb7dd2d88]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev+0x25)[0xb7e6c985]
./a.out[0x8048f5a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb7ba9637]
./a.out[0x8048b11]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
09621000-09646000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7a00000-b7a21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7a21000-b7b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7b39000-b7b3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7b3c000-b7b8f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b8f000-b7b90000 r--p 00052000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b90000-b7b91000 rw-p 00053000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b91000-b7d41000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d41000-b7d43000 r--p 001af000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d43000-b7d44000 rw-p 001b1000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d44000-b7d47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7d47000-b7d63000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393625     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d63000-b7d64000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 393625     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d64000-b7ed1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed1000-b7ed2000 ---p 0016d000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed2000-b7ed7000 r--p 0016d000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed7000-b7ed8000 rw-p 00172000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed8000-b7edb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef0000-b7ef1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef1000-b7ef2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef2000-b7ef5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b7ef5000-b7ef7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7ef7000-b7f1a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7f1a000-b7f1b000 r--p 00022000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7f1b000-b7f1c000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bfaf8000-bfb19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb7bf8377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb7bf8377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb7bfe2f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb7bfe2f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dc31)[0xb7bfec31]
(+0x6dc31)[0xb7bfec31]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb7dd2d88]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb7dd2d88]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev+0x25)[0xb7e6c985]
./a.out[0x8048f5a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev+0x25)[0xb7e6c985]
./a.out[0x8048f5a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb7ba9637]
./a.out[0x8048b11]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1052404    /home/f178082/a.out
09621000-09646000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7a00000-b7a21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7a21000-b7b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7b39000-b7b3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7b3c000-b7b8f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b8f000-b7b90000 r--p 00052000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b90000-b7b91000 rw-p 00053000 08:01 393657     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
b7b91000-b7d41000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d41000-b7d43000 r--p 001af000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d43000-b7d44000 rw-p 001b1000 08:01 393587     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
b7d44000-b7d47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7d47000-b7d63000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393625     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d63000-b7d64000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 393625     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7d64000-b7ed1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed1000-b7ed2000 ---p 0016d000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed2000-b7ed7000 r--p 0016d000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed7000-b7ed8000 rw-p 00172000 08:01 785415     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
b7ed8000-b7edb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef0000-b7ef1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef1000-b7ef2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7ef2000-b7ef5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]
b7ef5000-b7ef7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7ef7000-b7f1a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7f1a000-b7f1b000 r--p 00022000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
b7f1b000-b7f1c000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 393559     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
bfaf8000-bfb19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you verified that alu works correctly by running it directly?

Comment: you mean by passing arguments from the terminal? Yes I have verified it works

Comment: `char a1[arg1.size()+1];` and the following two are VLA's which is not standard C++. It might be accepted by your compiler but it's not portable. `std::vector` is the better alternative. And as a note: Some people might downvote your question because your code is missing indentation, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: @churill thank you I'll make sure my code is indented next time and I'll give a go to your suggestion too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to pass 3 arguments, but *four*. Remember that the first argument (argv[0], since arrays are zero based) is supposed to be the program name. And you must allso NULL-terminate the array.

So you have to do:

```
const char *args[5];

args[0]=path;
args[1]=arg1.c_str();
args[2]=op.c_str();
args[3]=arg2.c_str();
args[4]=NULL;
```

Edit:

I also forgot that `execv()` is buggy. It is declared `int execv(const char *pathname, char *const argv[]);` Rather than `int execv(const char *pathname, const char *const argv[]);` So this is one of the few cases when it is OK to use pointer casting:

```
 execv(path, (char **)args);
```

Or maybe drop `args[]` all together and use `execl()`:

```
 execl(path, path,  arg1.c_str(), op.c_str(), arg2.c_str(), NULL);
```

Comment: The array should be null terminated too

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: c++ CPU.cpp -o a.out
CPU.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
CPU.cpp:39:8: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
 args[0]=path;

An error occurs when i try to do so

Comment: You have to declare `const char *args[5]` and not `char *args[5]`. Remember that `path` and `std::string::c_str()` are `const char *`

Comment: I did as you said but there's yet another error I changed char *args[4] to const char *args[5] and NULL terminated the array as well but I got this error now 

error: invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’ [-fpermissive]
 execv(path,args);

I'll add the updated section of the code in the post too